# Docker php set up installing pdo extension

Tags: php, nginx, pdo, docker

I am using docker to build my dev enviroment, a very simple env where all i have is nginx and php-fpm.

So following docker docks I have created a docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
image: nginx:latest
ports:
    - "80:80"
volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
links:
    - php
```

php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./code:/code

So what happens here i call nginx image and pgp-fpm image and link them.

I have also created a site.conf file:

```
server {
    index index.php;
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
   }
}
```

So here is all the server stuff.

with this set up i have sucesfully runned `phpinfo()`. When i However aded my app code i get an error complaning about pdo pdo_mysql extensions. So i did more research and found out i need a Dockerfile.

I created a docker file and and inside it added this commands:

```
FROM php:7
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Of course this does not work, I mean where does this install the extensions and how does my php-fpm supoose to see these extensions...?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs on the PHP repository in Dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ ? I've done this with the apache version, not fpm. With the apache version you create a Dockerfile and install any pre-reqs and `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql`. I assume there is a similar method for FPM, see that readme and the corresponding github repo.

Comment: Have you run `docker-compose build` before running `docker-compose up -d`?

Answer (score 3):

This Dockerfile help me:

```
FROM php:fpm
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql
```

And this is part my docker-composer.yml

```
phpfpm:
  build: 
      context: ./php-fpm
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: test-php-fpm
  links:
      - mysql
  volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
```